# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (It wont work)

Tags: python

```
   filename = input("[+]Enter the filename containing the usernames to check (IE userlist.txt): ") 
   print '1.txt'
```

I am new to coding and I want it to write "1.txt" where it asks for the file name, can anyone help me do that. Also is there a way to make it click enter? If someone can help it would mean a lot.

Comment: Looks like your indentation is broken. Shift `print` to the left and retry.

Comment: Why are you trying to feed input to your own `input()` function?

Comment: I  did, I am running a  infinite while loop and I had to tab everything over. 

Before it wanted me to type the file name in and click enter, I am trying to make it do that itself basically.

Comment: @jwodder I am new to this, just looking for help. what should I put there?

Comment: @XavierHanson: Well, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jwodder I want it to load a text file, its a checker and it checks the words on the text file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Based on the revision history, it looks like indentation is off due to your changes. If you think the issue OP has mentioned is due to indentation, you should be mentioning it as comment instead of changing it yourself.

Comment: Please post the syntax error. Is it `Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`? In that case, it means that you are using a python 2 style print statement in python 3. Your original post before people messed up the indentation ran without a syntax error on python 2

Comment: @tdelaney I am  trying now to get "1.txt" posted on the same line that asks for the file name, anyway to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want the "1.txt" to be already there as a default value, so the user just presses Enter if that's what they want?

Comment: @keith I want the program to start and type 1.txt and then click enter. so I dont have to do anything.

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question describing exactly what it is you are trying to do, and what you have tried, and what you are seeing instead.

Comment: you can only do `if filename == '': filename = "1.txt"` and inform user to use only Enter/Return to use default name `"1.txt"` - ie. `input("[+]Enter name or press 'Return' to use name '1.txt'")`